# Extrair chave privada de um arquivo com a extenção .DER

Tags: php, ubuntu, openssl

Preciso extrair a chave privada de um arquivo `.DER`, entretanto analisando a função [openssl_pkey_get_private](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php) identifiquei que é necessário passar como parâmetro um arquivo com a extenção `.PEM`.

Tentei ver o conteúdo do certificado utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.der -inform der -text -noout
```

Porém ocorreu o seguinte erro:

> unable to load certificate
>   140492645532928:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1112:
>   140492645532928:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:274:Type=X509_CINF
>   140492645532928:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:609:Field=cert_info, Type=X509

Tentei converter do formato `.DEM` para o formato `.PEM` utilizando o seguinte comando, porém é necessário um arquivo com o formato `.CRT` que não tenho:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -inform der -outform pem -out cert.pem
```

**É possível extrair a chave privada de um arquivo com a extenção `.DER`?**

Comment: Se não me engano a opção `x509` só funciona se o arquivo contém um certificado (sem a chave privada). Se o arquivo contém somente a chave, uma alternativa para convertê-lo é usar [`openssl rsa`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288744) (assumindo que a chave é RSA). Se o arquivo contém o certificado e a chave privada (é um pfx, jks, etc), você pode usar `openssl pkcs12`.

Comment: @hkotsubo a chave é sim RSA porém o ficheiro .der só contém a chave privada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não me engano a opção `x509` só funciona se o arquivo contém um certificado (sem a chave privada).

Como no seu caso o arquivo só tem a chave privada RSA ([conforme dito nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/311509/extrair-chave-privada-de-um-arquivo-com-a-exten%C3%A7%C3%A3o-der?noredirect=1#comment632578_311509)), a opção `rsa` deve funcionar. Para convertê-la de DER para PEM, faça:

```
openssl rsa -inform der -outform pem -in chaveprivada.der -out chaveprivada.pem
```

Com isso, o arquivo `chaveprivada.der` é convertido para PEM, e o resultado estará no arquivo `chaveprivada.pem`.